# What is a depth image?

Tags: ros, camera-depth-points, webcam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is a depth image? Does it require a special hardware? Can I get depth image from an inbuilt webcam?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256914/what-is-a-depth-image?/) by [Rai](https://answers.ros.org/users/29580/rai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2017-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the depth image each pixel value indicates a distance from the sensor. You cannot obtain this from an ordinary Webcam. Special Hardware is required, e.g. Kinect, Laser scanner or Stereo camera.

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2017-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rai](https://answers.ros.org/users/29580/rai/) on 2017-03-14**:
Thank you for your answer. So, you're saying in [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/256226/find-3d-location-of-the-sensor-when-a-depth-image-arrives/) I make no sense? So can I draw your attention to the question in the link? Where should I start and what would I need to make it?